# remove only some html tags on c#

Tags: c#, html

I have a string:

```
string hmtl = "<DIV><B> xpto </B></DIV>
```

and need to remove the tags of  `<div>` and `</DIV>`. With a result of : `<B> xpto </B>`

---

Just `<DIV> and </DIV>` without the removal of a lot of html tags, but save the `<B> xpto </B>`.

Comment: Is it just `<DIV>` and `</DIV>` that you want to remove?

Comment: Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for such tasks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You should post that as an answer

Comment: no, <DIV> and </DIV> was a exemple, i wont remove a lot of html tag, but save de <B> and </B>. thanks

Comment: yes, i only take the <B> and </B> tag (tag for bold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Regex`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(html, @"</?DIV>", "");
```

**UPDATED**

as you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143563/remove-only-some-html-tags-on-c-sharp#comment17878191_13143563), by this code, regex removes all tages else `B`

```
var hmtl = "<DIV><B> xpto </B></DIV>";
var remainTag = "B";
var pattern = String.Format("(</?(?!{0})[^<>]*(?<!{0})>)", remainTag );
var result =  Regex.Replace(hmtl , pattern, "");
```

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen Why does everyone refer to that old chest-nut post about OOHH REGEX IS EVIL - DO NOT USE post?! Seriously... not everything has to go through HTML Agility Pack!

Comment: that post is so funny it hurts. and true. thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<html>yourHtml</html>");

foreach(var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))// "//div" is a xpath which means select div nodes that are anywhere in the html
{
 item.InnerHtml;//your div content
}
```

If you want only B tags..

```
foreach(var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//B"))
    {
     item.OuterHtml;//your B tag and its content
    }
```

Comment: who i transforme my string to a htmldocument, which is the library i need to use HtmlDocumen?? thanks

Comment: This is a good answer, but what if I want to pass it a set of tags, like <p> <a> <li>, etc? Say I want to create a function that I can pass a list of tags into (string lists that is)?

Comment: @Fernando68 since its an xpath , you can use multiple or conditions like 
`//p | //a | //li `

Answer (score 5):

If you are just removing div tags, this will get `div` tags as well as any attributes they may have.

```
var html = 
  "<DIV><B> xpto <div text='abc'/></B></DIV><b>Other text <div>test</div>" 

var pattern = "@"(\</?DIV(.*?)/?\>)"";  

// Replace any match with nothing/empty string
Regex.Replace(html, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Result**

```
<B> xpto </B><b>Other text test
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular

```
<[(/body|html)\s]*>
```

in c#:

```
 var result = Regex.Replace(html, @"<[(/body|html)\s]*>", "");

<html>
<body>
< / html> 
< / body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html = Regex.Replace(html,@"<*DIV>", String.Empty);
```