# remove html tags regexp except for <p> and </p>

Tags: c#, html, regex

I would like to remove all html tags except for the `<p>` and `</p>` tags

I'm working in c#

For example:   `<p>`hello`<a href=kuku>` to you`</a>` `</p>`

should return  `<p>`hello to you`</p>`

P.S. I'm using the regexp function but am open to suggestions

Comment: your question is too long.

Comment: This has been answered about a million times already here on SO.  Here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143563/remove-only-some-html-tags-on-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple regex:

```
<(?!/?p>)[^<>]*>
```

See the substitutions at the bottom of **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/3)**.

**In C#:**

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(yourString, 
                              "<(?!/?p>)[^<>]*>", "", 
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Explanation**

- `<` matches an opening tag
- The negative lookahead `(?!/?p>)` asserts that what follows is not an optional slash and a closing tag `>`
- `[^<>]*` matches any chars that are not `<` or `>`
- `>` matches the closing tag
- We replace with the empty string